# Joomla: Publish/Unpublish via command line

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla site on a test system and I have a 99% automated process for copying the site over to my hosting provider when I want to update the hosted site.

The last 1% is related to ads from Google AdSense.  There is a big problem with the process for testing ads (there is no process).  Google also says that using real ads in a test environment will get your account banned.

Ok - to work around this, I use 2 modules.  The first module is the official Google Adsense ad display. The other module is an ad that I created myself that is the same size. I use the "fake" ad on the test system and the Google ad on the hosted site I have one or the other published to display ads at any given time.

As I said, I have an automated process to copy my test site over to the hosting server.  What I need is an automated way to unpublish the "fake ad" module and publish the Google ad module before copying the site over to the hosting server.

If given an option, I would prefer a SQL solution (I know SQL much better), but  a PHP solution is fine too.

Joomla version 3.4.8
MySQL version 5.5
O/S Fedora 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install the module for displaying Google AdSense on Joomla! website. I have installed Phoca GAE (Google AdSense Easy module - http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-gae - http://www.phoca.cz/phoca-googleadsense) which allows me to set substitute for ads

2) Create first instance of this module with real Google AdSense code and set the field NOTE to "real" (Note = real)

3) Create second instance of this module, paste testing code, e.g.:

```
<div style="background:yellow;width:468px;height:60px"> </div>
```

(this will display yellow background, set the size of your ads)
Set the field NOTE to "fake" (Note = fake)

Now there are two same modules, set the same position for them.

You can switch between them with help of this SQL queries.

Display real module and hide testing module:

```
UPDATE `jos_modules` SET published =0 WHERE note = 'fake';
UPDATE `jos_modules` SET published =1 WHERE note = 'real';
```

Display testing module and hide real module:

```
UPDATE `jos_modules` SET published =1 WHERE note = 'fake';
UPDATE `jos_modules` SET published =0 WHERE note = 'real';
```

- you can set own html code to display fake/tested ads
- you can set own name in form field "note"
- change database prefix to your own ( jos_ to your_own_prefix_ )
- don't forget to set unique name for "note" so no other modules will be published/unpublished
- note form field you can see in the right bottom place of module settings

Comment: Thanks - that was the SQL I was looking for.